# How to autoload multiple classes in Yii extension?

Tags: php, yii

I am not sure whether title of question is exactly what I want to ask.

I want to use Authorize.net in my Yii application. Authorize.net has an API consisting of multiple classes and in order for the API to work all the classes should be autoloaded. In its SDK there is one file named autoload.php that does that. Please note that autoload.php is NOT a class, it just contains a function. Here is its code:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
static $classMap;

if (!isset($classMap)) {
    $classMap = require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classmap.php';
}

if (isset($classMap[$className])) {
    include $classMap[$className];
}
});
```

By requiring this file in my code I can do work with API successfully. Like:

```
require 'sdk-php-master/autoload.php
//I can make successful API calls after requiring autoload.php to be loaded.
```

But now the problem is I want to make same API work in Yii. I placed the SDK folder in extensions directory. Now I need to set extension path to be able to use it in my application. Now the problem is what should I set in class name for in config.php to make it work?

I tried this:

```
'authorize' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.authorize.autoload',
        ),
```

But that does not work, and it should not since autoload.php is not a class. All the necessary classes that should be autoloaded are placed in `application.extensions.authorize.lib` directory. How should I autoload all of them in Yii since according to my knowledge we can only have one entry in config.php for class.

Here is the link to SDK and its directory structure. [Authorize.net SDK](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. I just imported all the required folders in config main.php like this:

```
 'import' => array(
        'application.extensions.*',
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.extensions.authorize.*',
        'application.extensions.authorize.lib.*',
        'application.extensions.authorize.lib.shared.*',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This library uses [composer](https://getcomposer.org), i recommend to you [to use composer in your project](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer/) to manage your libraries, and you will have no hassle with autloads.

Basicly create composer.json in your root project directory and place authorize part in it (and any further things)

```
{
    "require": {
    "authorizenet/authorizenet": "~1.8"
    }
}
```

In your main index.php place:

```
require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

somewhere before `require $yii`

Then call `composer install`. This in in short, for more details about composer [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer/) should be fine.

**Update:**
Composer will greatly improve your workflow when your require some external libraries. However if you really don't wan't to use composer, then just require `autoload.php` in `index.php`

Then use this library classes as in docs. Do not configure it as extension - this library is not Yii specific. In any code part just use it, for example:

```
define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "YOURLOGIN");
define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "YOURKEY");
$subscription                          = new AuthorizeNet_Subscription;
$subscription->name                    = "PHP Monthly Magazine";
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Any other way to do that without using composer?

Comment: I updated answer, perhaps it will be now more clear:)

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload all Authorize.net files using the following code on your `protected/config/main.php` file:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Authorize', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/sdk-php-master');
Yii::import('Authorize.autoload', true);
```